# index was out of range. I can't figure out why

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am making a search bar for my windows form application. I have `DataGridView` , `TextBox` and a `ComboBox`

I have this code in my class :

```
Classes.dbConnect _db = new Classes.dbConnect();    

public void SearchPosition()
{
    if (_search.Equals("POSITION"))
    {
        _db._conn.Open();
        string com = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Candidates" + " WHERE ( Position LIKE @pos )";
        _db._com = new SqlCommand(com, _db._conn);
        _db._com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pos", "%" + _position + "%");

        try
        {
            _db._da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            _db._da.SelectCommand = _db._com;
            DataTable _dt = new DataTable();
            _db._da.Fill(_dt);
            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = _dt;
            _dg.DataSource = bs;
            _db._da.Update(_dt);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
                _db._conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have my textbox = TxtSearch.Text

```
private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Classes.Admin.Candidates.position = txtSearch.Text;
    cand.SearchPosition();
}
```

And I have my combobox = cboCategory; Item inside is "Position"

```
private void cboCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Classes.Admin.Candidates.search = cboCategory.Text;
}
```

When I start typing in my TxtSearch.Text. Every letter searches the database with the same value as the TxtSearch.Text.

The `DataGridView` only shows the value same as the value in the `TextBox`.
But when the `DataGridView` is empty already, i keep getting the error.

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: Index

Answer (score 0):

I would say you could try to do a `try catch` block, and whenever the the datagridview is empty or null, you throw an exception. That way the application doesn't crash, and the user is noticed of what happened

Comment: Pinto, Thanks.. I kinda know how to do try catch, but im still new at this, i dont know how to do exception when datagridview is empty or null..